# @Valid @RequestBody giving Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am facing a strange issue with Spring validation. I am trying to validate the bean with Spring anotation using Integration test. However below is the issue I am facing with different implementaion.

**1) When I try  @Valid @RequestBody TaskApprovalDetails taskApprovalDetails ( TaskApprovalDetails is my bean), I get below exception**

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.(InterpolationTerm.java:59)

```
Please note without @Valid, @RequestBody is able to map my json to taskApprovalDetails.
```

**2) When  I try    @Valid @ModelAttribute("taskApprovalDetails") TaskApprovalDetails taskApprovalDetails I dont get any exception. I am able to reach to my controller, but all the properties in taskApprovalDetails object are null. @ModelAttribute not able to map my request json to objet**

Below are some sample code :

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{taskId}/{customerId}/accept", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void acceptTask(@PathVariable String taskId, @PathVariable String customerId, @RequestParam("user") String user,
                    @Valid @ModelAttribute("taskApprovalDetails") TaskApprovalDetails taskApprovalDetails) throws URISyntaxException, ParseException {
        inboxService.acceptTask(taskApprovalDetails, user, taskId, customerId);
}
```

**OR**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{taskId}/{customerId}/accept", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void acceptTask(@PathVariable String taskId, @PathVariable String customerId, @RequestParam("user") String user,
               @Valid @RequestBody TaskApprovalDetails taskApprovalDetails) throws URISyntaxException, ParseException {
        inboxService.acceptTask(taskApprovalDetails, user, taskId, customerId);
}
```

**json**

```
public static String mockJsonRequestBody(final String customerId, final String role) {
     return "{\"comments\":\"Click\",\"role\":\"User\",\"userId\":\"asdasdasd\"}";
}
```

**TaskApprovalDetails.class**

```
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class TaskApprovalDetails {

    private int rowId;
    private String role;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=20, max = 25)
    private String userId;
    private Date taskCreatedDate;
    private Date taskCompletedDate;
    private String decision;
    private BigDecimal level;
    @Size(min = 20, max = 25, message = "Comments can be between 20-25 char only.")
    private String comments;
    private String rejectedSection;
    private List<String> businessRestriction;
```

Please suggest me which is the best approach to validate the bean. @ModelAtrubute or @RequestBody and how to fix the above issue.

Comment: 1. do you have json library on classpath? ( is it added to your pom.xml? ) 2. ModelAttribute can be used if you are using 'normal' POST from html form - in case of json use @RequestBody

Comment: @freakman : Thanks for your reply. Yes I do have json library added in pom.

Comment: I have tried one thing : Adding default message in my model  
@NotBlank(message="USERID_CANNOT_BE_BLANK")
    private String userId;

And my test is executing with @RequestBody. I am not getting the com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found at .. exception. Any idea why its failing without degault message? Any specific dependency is missing ?